# Removing spaces from multiple string items in a list in python

Tags: python, string, list, whitespace, strip

I have a list of string items in python:

`positions = ['CF', 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']`

I want to remove the spaces from the items which contain spaces (e.g. `' RAMF'`).

I have tried this using the following code:

```
positions = [x.strip(' ') for x in positions]
# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

player_positions = [x.text.strip(' ') for x in player_positions]
# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'

positions = map(str.strip, positions)
# <map at 0x7fde15d19a90>
```

How can I remove the spaces in any list item that contains a space here?

Comment: The first one should work fine.  Seems like something else is missing.

Comment: I would guess your positions list has an empty item. i.e. ''

Comment: The data you show and the error message you provide do not match. Even if you had an empty string in your list, it would not give you `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'` - that only happens for `None` values.

Comment: Using strip will only remove the spaces from the beginning and/or end of your strings. Is that what you want?

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution (Edited):

```
positions = ['CF', 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']    
positions = [x.strip(" ") for x in positions]
```

Comment: what if it is mixed list including numbers? 'str' works on list mixed with string and integers without any errors.

Comment: @Rahil If the original list contains a number your code will convert it into a string

Comment: yes i see the issue, i have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I speculate that maybe your actual list contains some items which are not strings.  Flush them out using this list comprehension:

```py
bad_positions = [p for p in positions if not isinstance(p, str)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The question may be ambiguous so I'll offer 3 options:

```
positions = ['CF', 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']

# replace all/any spaces
positions = [p.replace(' ', '') for p in positions]
# remove leading and trailing spaces
positions = [p.strip(' ') for p in positions]
# remove leading and trailing whitespace
positions = [p.strip() for p in positions]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your given list

`positions = ['CF', 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']`

and codes will not result in **all** of your errors. Especially

> ```
> positions = [x.strip(' ') for x in positions]
> ```

would simply work.

---

This can be deducted from your messages:

> ```
> positions = [x.strip(' ') for x in positions]
> # AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'
> ```

*The error tells you that there is at least one element in `positions` that is `None` - and not a string.*

> ```
> player_positions = [x.text.strip(' ') for x in player_positions]
> # AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'text'
> ```

*The error tells you that there is at least one element in `player_positions` that is a string - strings do not have an attribute `text`. If `player_positions`  is the same as `positions` it would mean that there is at least 1 string value before the `None` value.*

> ```
> positions = map(str.strip, positions)
> # <map at 0x7fde15d19a90>
> ```

`map` in python returns an iterator - the function is applied to your values at the time you iterate it - you don't thats why you get no exception yet. If iterated this gives a similar error to the 1st list._

---

You would get ALL the errors by doing:

```
p = ['CF', None, 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']

try:
    p1  = [x.strip(' ') for x in p]
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e)
```

==> `<class 'AttributeError'> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

```
try:
    p2  = [x.text.strip(' ') for x in p]
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e)
```

==> `<class 'AttributeError'> 'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

```
try:
    p3  = map(str.strip, p)
    p3l = list(p3)
except Exception as e:
    print(type(e), e)
```

==> `<class 'TypeError'> descriptor 'strip' for 'str' objects doesn't apply to a 'NoneType' object`  which is similar to `<class 'AttributeError'> 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'`

---

Filtering out the None value from your data is probably your best guess:

```
filtered_pos = [p for p in positions if p is not None]
```

In case you only have strings and `None` in your data, you should be fine.

If you need to keep the non-strings/`None` intact, apply `strip()` only to strings:

```
p = ['CF', None, 'LCMF', 42, 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']

p1  = [x.strip(' ') if isinstance(x, str) else x for x in p]

print(p1)
```

will change only strings and leave the others alone:

```
['CF', None, 'LCMF', 42, 'AMF', 'LW', 'RAMF', 'LCMF', 'AMF', 'RB']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use string replace function as I mentioned below.

```
positions = ['CF', 'LCMF', 'RW', 'AMF', 'LW', ' RAMF', ' LCMF', ' AMF', ' RB']

print([position.replace(' ','') for position in positions])
```